# sql query to check 2 records in a table if a specific value has changed

Tags: sql, date, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I've got a table which has the following data:

```
Date,         Id,      hash,      Timestamp
----          --       ------     ---------
2020-05-21    001      abc123     07:00am
2020-05-21    001      abc123     08:00am
2020-05-21    001      def456     09:00am
2020-05-21    002      dddddd     07:00am
2020-05-21    002      dddddd     08:00am
2020-05-21    002      dddddd     09:00am
2020-05-21    003      222222     07:00am
2020-05-21    003      qqqwww     08:00am
2020-05-21    003      qqqwww     09:00am
```

I need a query which will check the latest records (9am records) and compare them against the previous record inserted for that id (8am records) and check if the hash value is different. Only want a list of the 9am records which have a changed hashvalue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 1):

You could use window functions, if your database supports them:

```
select t.*
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by timestamp desc) rn,
        lag(hash)    over(partition by id order by timestamp) lag_hash
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1 and hash <> lag_hash
```

This assumes that the `timestamp` column is of a date-like datatype (or, at least, that in can be used to properly sort the records).